# Java - merge two lists removing duplicates based on the value of a property

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a class like this:

```
public class MyObject {
  private Long id;
  private String firstProp;
  private String secondProp;
  private Boolean isLatest;
}
```

In my app, I get two lists, one that will definitely have `isLatest` set (`Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`) and the other list that will definitely have `isLatest` set to `null`

I want a resulting `List` or `Set` which contains items from both lists but duplicates removed where `isLatest == null`. That is, while removing duplicates, I want to retain the elements where `isLatest != null`. The definition of duplicates is same `id`.

`equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in `MyObject` are based on `id`, `firstProp` and `secondProp` and cannot be changed as they are predefined and changing them will disturb other parts of the app.

```
List<MyObject> listWithIsLatestSet = list with items below
myObj1 --> id = 1, isLatest = true;
myObj2 --> id = 2, isLatest = false;
myObj3 --> id = 3, isLatest = true;
myObj4 --> id = 4, isLatest = true;

List<MyObject> listWithIsLatestNull = list with items below
myObj5 --> id = 1, isLatest = null;
myObj6 --> id = 2, isLatest = null;
myObj7 --> id = 5, isLatest = null;
```

The resulting list would look like below:

```
myObj1 --> id = 1, isLatest = true;
myObj2 --> id = 2, isLatest = false;
myObj3 --> id = 3, isLatest = true;
myObj4 --> id = 4, isLatest = true;
myObj7 --> id = 5, isLatest = null;
```

Can this be advised, please?

### THIS WORKED FOR ME

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MAIN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<MyObject> setWithIsLatestSet = getSetWithIsLatestSet();
        Set<MyObject> setWithIsLatestNull = getSetWithIsLatestNull();
        setWithIsLatestSet.addAll(setWithIsLatestNull);
        setWithIsLatestSet.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Set<MyObject> getSetWithIsLatestSet() {
        MyObject obj1 = MyObject.builder().id(new Long(1)).isLatest(Boolean.TRUE).build();
        MyObject obj2 = MyObject.builder().id(new Long(2)).isLatest(Boolean.FALSE).build();
        MyObject obj3 = MyObject.builder().id(new Long(3)).isLatest(Boolean.TRUE).build();
        MyObject obj4 = MyObject.builder().id(new Long(4)).isLatest(Boolean.TRUE).build();
        MyObject obj5 = MyObject.builder().id(new Long(5)).isLatest(Boolean.TRUE).build();

        return Stream.of(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    }

    private static Set<MyObject> getSetWithIsLatestNull() {
        MyObject obj1 = MyObject.builder().id(new Long(1)).build();
        MyObject obj2 = MyObject.builder().id(new Long(2)).build();
        MyObject obj6 = MyObject.builder().id(new Long(6)).build();
        MyObject obj7 = MyObject.builder().id(new Long(7)).build();

        return Stream.of(obj1, obj2, obj6, obj7).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
    }
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
class MyObject {
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;
    private Boolean isLatest;
}
```

### Output:

MyObject(id=5, isLatest=true)

MyObject(id=6, isLatest=null)

MyObject(id=7, isLatest=null)

MyObject(id=1, isLatest=true)

MyObject(id=2, isLatest=false)

MyObject(id=3, isLatest=true)

MyObject(id=4, isLatest=true)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you stuck on something specific? FYI, StackOverflow isn't a code generation service, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried a couple of things. I merged the two lists as is and then used ```stream().filter(a -> a.getIsLatest() == null).collect(Collectors.toList())``` but that would remove all the objects from ```listWithIsLatestNull```. The other thing I tried is to write a ```distinctByKey``` function that returns a predicate, but that didn't do the trick either because in this case it will try to filter out the elements based on value of distinct values of ```isLatest```

Comment: Ok, so add the code to your question so we can see what you've tried and can better aide you in figuring out what's not working.

Comment: sounds like a duplicate of [Java stream remove duplicate list of objects of list property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405305)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Work fine for your example,

```
BinaryOperator<MyObject> mergeFunction = (old, lst) -> {
    if (lst.getLatest() != null && lst.getLatest()) {return lst;}
    else if (old.getLatest() == null && lst.getLatest() == null) {return lst;}
    else if (old.getLatest() == null && lst.getLatest() != null && !lst.getLatest()) {return lst;}
    else {return old;}
};

List<MyObject> collect = new ArrayList<>(Stream.concat(listWithIsLatestSet.stream(), listWithIsLatestNull.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getId, Function.identity(), mergeFunction))
        .values());
```

Comment: Thank you, ray. After trying (I updated the post with what I tried) my solution, I tried yours as well. And this works like a charm. Thanks!!!

Comment: @curious_brain glad to help!